# In angular.js, can a directive controller access data in a page controller that loaded it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

In angular.js, can a directive controller access data in a page controller that loaded it?

```
/**
 * Profile directive
 */
    .directive('profile', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/partials/users/_profile.html',
            scope: {
                user: '=',
                show: '=?'
            },
            controller: function($scope, $rootScope){
                $scope.show = angular.isDefined($scope.show) ? $scope.show : { follow: true, link: true };
                $scope.currentUser = $rootScope.currentUser;

                //do stuff here and then set data in UserShowCtrl
            }
        };
    });
```

The `<profile user="user"></profile>` method is called from `./users/show.html` which uses the UserShowCtrl controller.

Is there anyway I can use scope on the profile directive with its own controller and still be able to pass data to the UserShowCtrl?

Even though the profile can be isolated to its own functionality, it still needs to set some data on the page level in the UserShowCtrl controller.

Here is where _user.html is loading the `<profile>` directive. The data for the page is served by the `UserShowCtrl` and has some collections that get updated when things happen, like following a user.

```
<ol class="following" ng-show="showConnections == 'following'">
    <li ng-repeat="following in user.following">
        <profile user="connections[following]"></profile>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Right now there is an `ng-click="follow(user)">` that is happening in the _profile.html. I would like to be able to have the directive handle this but also update the collections in the UserShowCtrl.

Edit: here is a plunker demonstrating what I'm trying to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9a5dxMVg9cKLptxnNfX3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service in order to share any information between controllers, directives, services

something like

```
  angular.module('myapp',[]).
  service('myservice',function(){
      return {a:'A',b:'B'}
  }).
  controller('mycontroller',['myservice',function(myservice){

        //do someting with myservice    

  }]).
  directive('mydirective',['myservice',function(myservice){

        //do someting with myservice    

  }]);
```

there controller and directive access the same data through  the service

Comment: can i change `myservice.a = 'aaaa';` inside `mydirective` and it will reflect inside `mycontroller` too?

Comment: yes, because you are operating over a the service parameter aslong as you do myservice.a your changes will be reflected in the service and then be visible to anyone who has a reference to the service

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent scope from your directive with $scope.$parent.myvar.

myvar will be resolved in parent scope, which means prototypical scope inheritance is used to resolve the variable.

However, this does not guarantee that myvar is coming from the same scope as UserShowCtrl since its possible that any scope in between the 'profile' directive and UserShowCtrl's scope may override 'myvar'.

A better solution would be to use directive-to-directive communication. There are generally two ways for directives to communicate:

1. Through attributes passed into your directive. You've already used this method to import 'user' and 'show' from parent scope into your directive's isolated scope.
2. Requiring another directive. When you use 'require: ^UserShow', you are specifying that your 'profile' directive requires another directive as a dependency. The '^' means that it will search for the directive on the current element, or any parent element further up the DOM tree. UserShow's controller is then passed to your link function:

   ```
    .directive('UserShow', function () {
     return {
           restrict: 'E',
           controller: function($scope){
                 $scope.myvar = 'test';
                 this.setMyVar = function(var) {
                     $scope.myvar = var;
                 }
               }
           };
       });

   .directive('profile', function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace: true,
           templateUrl: '/partials/users/_profile.html',
           require: '^UserShow',
           scope: {
               user: '=',
               show: '=?'
           },
           controller: function($scope, $rootScope){
           },
           link: function(scope, element, attr, UserShowCtrl) {
               UserShowCtrl.setMyVar('hello world!);
           }

       };
   });
   ```

HTML:

```
  <user-show>
       <profile>...</profile>
  </user-show>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your after.

You are already having 2 two-way data bindings, which means that if you change user in your directive, that will also flow to the outside scope.

So you already have a solution in front of you...
So if that is not "good enough", there is something missing in your question.

Here is an illustration: http://plnkr.co/edit/qEH2Pr1Pv7MTdXjHd4bD?p=preview

However, if you use something in your outside template that creates a child scope, binding it as "value" there is NOT enough, you need to have a . in there.

But that is where there is missing something to the question, if you share your show.html I may be able to find where the scope breaks apart and explain why...

---

Relevant Source from demo.js:

```
app.directive('profile', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="user"></input></div>',
            scope: { //defines an isolate scope.
                user: '=',
                show: '=?'
            },
            controller: function($scope, $rootScope){
                $scope.show = angular.isDefined($scope.show) ? $scope.show : { follow: true, link: true };
                $scope.currentUser = $rootScope.currentUser;

                $scope.user = "Changed by scope!";
                //do stuff here and then set data in UserShowCtrl
            }
        };
    });

app.controller('UserShowCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = "Value set outside!";

  $scope.alertValue = function() {
    alert($scope.value);
  }
});
```

Relevant Source from home.html:

```
<div ng-controller="UserShowCtrl">
  {{ value }}
  <profile user="value"></profile>
  <button ng-click="alertValue()">ALERT!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what happens. Once I defined a scope and a controller in my directive, all connection to the page controller is severed.

Comment: You have created an Isolate Scope with scope: {}.. but you have said to angular that it should create a 2-way binding for user as well as an optional 2-way binding for show.

Comment: Added some more information as well as an example where you can see that it works...

Comment: I am a bit confused about that plunker, it doesn't seem like your using the UserShowCtrl anywhere or includes the _user.html in any places... Have you by any chance forgotten to save the last part of it?

Comment: In this case, how to call alertValue() function from profile directive template?